# Spring REST return object into json with extra line appended

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I have been trying to return a JSON object along with an extra value appended.

right now this code returns a json of an object

```
@GetMapping("/getProduct")
    public Product getProduct(@RequestParam String productId){
        return productService.getById(productId);
    }
```

it returns:

```
{
  "productId": "1",
  "productName": "product1",
  "productPrice": 100.0,
  "imageLink": null
}
```

but i want to add an extra line so it returns:

```
{
  "productId": "1",
  "productName": "product1",
  "productPrice": 100.0,
  "imageLink": null
  "customVariable": somethingsomething
}
```

all the examples i can find either return only the object, or build a json from scratch. Is there any way to append the variable to the object?

Comment: why not add `customVariable` this property in `Product` class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - You can add the `customVariable` field to the `Product` entity.

```java
public class Product {
    
    private String productId;
    private String productName;
    private Double productPrice;
    private String imageLink;
    private String customVariable;

    public Product() {
    }
    
    // getter/setter ..
}
```

2 - If you want to add an extra field without modifying the `Product` entity:

```java
@GetMapping("/getProduct")
public String getProduct(@RequestParam String productId){
Product product = productService.getById(productId);
    Product product = productService.getById(productId);
    JsonNode node = objectMapper.convertValue(teacher, JsonNode.class);
    ((ObjectNode)node).put("customVariable", "somethingsomething");
    return node.toString();
}
```